# Get code for your action and see in my timeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm building an Open Graph action.
Before I was using curl in command line in order to post in my timeline, now when I'm using this command, nothing appears in my timeline.
The response is correct in the graph. And I can see my all those actions on my graph but still nothing on my timeline https://graph.facebook.com/me/[namespace]:[action]?access_token=[...]

I don't understand what is happening

I'm using fb_graph gem in the back-end

```
  def self.action(objet, user, url)
    me = current_user.facebook
    Thread.new do
     sleep(4)
     action = me.og_action!(
        FACEBOOK_NAMESPACE+":action",
        :objet => url
        )
    end
  end
```

This has always worked

Any idea ?

Thanks
Maxime

Comment: Does it show up on your activity log ? Not all published actions are guaranteed to show up on your timeline, Facebook might filter out certain actions, but they will and should always show up on the activity log.

Comment: It doesn't show in my activity log app